# Nested Enums with Constructors & Methods?

Tags: java, data-structures, enums, inner-classes

I'm a Java student (relatively new) working on a game clone in Java as a side project. In the game, the player controls characters. Each character is part of a faction, and each faction has a set list of skills. The skills of one faction can not be used by any other faction. My idea for how to organize this is with nested enums, where a main `Skills` enum has multiple inner enums (`Faction1`, `Faction2`, etc). The idea is that I would be able to access the data for any specific skill using something along the lines of `Skills.Faction1.SKILL_NAME`, and to be able to access a full list of a faction's skills using `Skills.Faction1.values()`. A simplified example of a failed implementation of this is as follows:

```java
public enum Skills {
    FACTIONLESS_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"); //More skills than just this one
    
    enum Faction1 {
        FACTION1_FIRST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"), //More skills between the 2
        FACTION1_LAST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs");
        ...
    }
    
    enum Faction2 {
        FACTION2_FIRST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"), //More skills between the 2
        FACTION2_LAST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs");
        ...
    }
    
    String arbitraryField; //1 of many fields universal among both factionless and factioned skills
    
    Skills(String arbitraryArgs) { //1 of many universal constructors
        this.arbitraryField = arbitraryArgs;
    }

    void doUniversalThing() {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

When I try to use this implementation, I get errors telling me that the constructors and/or fields for the values in the inner enums don't exist. I tried copy pasting the constructors and fields into each individual inner enum, however that was both unreadable and unaccommodating to potential future skills which would not be attached to a faction. This simplified example doesn't even include all of the methods and alternate constructors that must be accessible to each skill. How could I implement this idea effectively and elegantly in a way that both supports skills which are a member of a faction and skills which are not, assuming that I could implement it at all? I tried my best to explain the intended results of the code, but if anything is still unclear then just let me know. Thank you.

Edit: The contents of `Faction1` were requested, so in additon to me rewriting my initial code example to maybe give a better idea of my intentions, here's a few different ways I've tried `Faction1`. All were either erroneous or just not ideal.

**Attempt 1:**

```java
public enum Skills {
    FACTIONLESS_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"); //More skills than just this one
    
    enum Faction1 {
        FACTION1_FIRST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"), //More skills between the 2
        FACTION1_LAST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs");
    }
    
    String arbitraryField; //1 of many fields universal among both factionless and factioned skills
    
    Skills(String arbitraryArgs) { //1 of many universal constructors
        this.arbitraryField = arbitraryArgs;
    }
}
```

My first attempt was just this, which gave me an error that `The constructor Skills.Faction2(String) is undefined`. I understand that this is due to `Faction2` being its own class and unable to use a `Skills` constructor, which is why I then moved to my second attempt.

**Attempt 2:**

```java
public enum Skills {
    FACTIONLESS_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"); //More skills than just this one
    
    enum Faction1 {
        FACTION1_FIRST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs"), //More skills between the 2
        FACTION1_LAST_SKILL("arbitraryArgs");
        
        String arbitraryField; Duplicates of Skills fields
        
        Faction1(String arbitraryArgs) { //Duplicate of Skills constructor
            this.arbitraryField = arbitraryArgs;
        }
    }
    
    String arbitraryField; //1 of many fields universal among both factionless and factioned skills
    
    Skills(String arbitraryArgs) { //1 of many universal constructors
        this.arbitraryField = arbitraryArgs;
    }
}
```

This solution *technically* works, in that there are no errors. However, my issue with this solution is the insane amount of code duplication this causes in my non-reduced program. Every skill has numerous fields, constructors, and methods, whether the skill is assigned to a faction or not. There are also numerous factions that would need to be made. If I ever realized that a field or method or constructor was either unneeded and should be removed or needed and should be created, I would need to create or remove it from every faction individually. This is just honestly not something I want to do on a silly side project.

I haven't thought of any other way to create these inner enums, nor have I seen any in my research, so these are my only 2 implementations so far. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Can you show the full content of the `Faction1` enum? Because you've omitted things that are definitely relevant. You can omit the constants themselves (let's keep the first and last ones), but all other stuff is very important here.

Comment: I commend you for tackling your learning through side projects.

Comment: Have you considered making `faction` an attribute of `Skills` and then simply making `SNIPER_SHOT` and `JUDGEMENT` values of `Skills`? Depending on how you write your code, you should be able to list Skills by faction if that was the reason you made them separate enums.

Comment: @RobSpoor I've updated my question with contents of `Faction1`, as well as just generally improved sample code to try and help clear things up a bit.

Comment: Consider making fraction an `enum` and using it just like any other parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decided to upgrade to Java 9 to use `Map.of()`. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

A brief OOPs class to begin with --
The `Faction` and `Skill` entities seem to have a `has a` relationship i.e., `A Factions HAS A set of Skills`. Also I will create an additional enum `SkillName` which again has a `HAS A` relation ship with `Skill`. So keeping these in mind you could arrange you enums like so --

```
public enum Faction {
    FACTION1(new HashMap<SkillName, Skill>(){{
        put(Skill.SNIPER_SHOT.skillName(), Skill.SNIPER_SHOT);
    }}),
    FACTION2(new HashMap<SkillName, Skill>(){{
        put(Skill.JUDGEMENT.skillName(), Skill.JUDGEMENT);
    }});

     Map<SkillName, Skill> skills;
    Faction(Map<SkillName, Skill> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public Skill[] skills(){
        return this.skills.values().toArray(new Skill[0]);
    }

    public Skill skill(SkillName name){
        Skill skill =  this.skills.get(name);
        if(Objects.isNull(skill)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Skill name");
        }
        return skill;
    }

}

enum SkillName {
    SNIPER_SHOT("SNIPER_SHOT"),
    JUDGEMENT("JUDGEMENT");
    String value;

    SkillName(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

}

enum Skill {
    SNIPER_SHOT(SkillName.SNIPER_SHOT, 0, 95, 5, new boolean[] {true, true, false, false}, new boolean[] {false, true, true, true}),
    JUDGEMENT(SkillName.JUDGEMENT,-25, 85, 5, new boolean[] {true, true, false, false}, new boolean[] {true, true, true, true});
    SkillName name;
    Integer dmg;
    Integer acc;
    Integer crit;
    boolean[] rank;
    boolean[] target;
    Skill(SkillName name, Integer dmg, Integer acc, Integer crit, boolean[] rank, boolean[] target) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dmg = dmg;
        this.acc = acc;
        this.crit = crit;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public SkillName skillName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now you could access the skills and a specific skill like so, --

```
Faction.FACTION1.skills();
Faction.FACTION2.skills();
Faction.FACTION1.skill(SkillName.SNIPER_SHOT);
Faction.FACTION1.skill(SkillName.JUDGEMENT); // this should throw exception
Faction.FACTION2.skill(SkillName.SNIPER_SHOT); // this should throw exception
Faction.FACTION2.skill(SkillName.JUDGEMENT);
```

The access patterns are not exactly the same as you wanted, but these work pretty much to the same extent.

**SIDE NOTE -**

Not sure what type of game you are developing, but in most of the games, skill of players improve (i.e. skill properties change) and players acquire new skills as well. Hence the above setup will become very rigid as enums are immutable and you will not be able to scale this. Instead, what I would suggest is that you create classes for Factions and Skills instead of enums. This way you would be able to mutate them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however what I did not mention within the post is that I came up with this idea for the exact reason to _avoid_ having maps. My system before this new syntax idea was something along the lines of

`Map<String, Skills[]> factionSkills = new HashMap<String, Skills>() {{put("FACTION_NAME", new Skills[] {SKILL1...});}}`.

However, if I'm unable to come up with a better solution, then I'll be sure to keep yours in mind! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already found your solution, but here is something that is probably much easier to use.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/** Enums. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71517372 */
public class SOQ_20220406_0201
{

   /**
    * 
    * Main method.
    * 
    * @param   args  commandline arguments, should they be needed.
    * 
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      enum Faction
      {
      
         F1,
         F2,
         F3,
         ALL,
         ;
      
      }
      
      enum Skill
      {
      
         SKILL_1(Faction.F1, "arbitraryArgs"),
         SKILL_2(Faction.F2, "arbitraryArgs"),
         SKILL_3(Faction.F3, "arbitraryArgs"),
         SKILL_ALL_CAN_USE(Faction.ALL, "arbitraryArgs"),
         ;
         
         private final Faction faction;
         private final String arbitraryArgs;
         
         Skill(Faction faction, String arbitraryArgs)
         {
         
            this.faction = faction;
            this.arbitraryArgs = arbitraryArgs;
         
         }
         
         public static List<Skill> fetchAllSkillsForFaction(final Faction faction)
         {
         
            return
               Arrays.stream(values())
                  .parallel()
                  .filter(each -> each.faction == faction)
                  .toList()
                  ;
         
         }
      
      }
      
      System.out.println(Skill.fetchAllSkillsForFaction(Faction.F1));
   
   }

}
```